# ASP.NET Core Razor unable to set cookies when using Apache as reverse proxy

Tags: c#, apache, cookies, reverse-proxy, asp.net-core-2.1

I am hosting my ASP.NET Core Razor application on CentOS using Apache as a reverse proxy. I am able to visit the website using my domain however the application is unable to set cookies in my browser no matter what I do.

This is the configuration for headers in my startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x"));
            options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
```

And this is virtual host configuration in apache httpd.conf file:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias subdomain.mysite.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5001/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5001/ retry=0
</VirtualHost>
```

I use this code for setting cookies and is not working:

```
 public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
Response.Cookies.Append("mycookie", "cookie-value");
                            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
}
```

I am not sure if I am doing everything correctly, perhaps I am going wrong somewhere but the fact is my application works fine on localhost and is able set cookies as well.

Comment: Use sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working and non working app.  Usually when you can't write is due to you attempting to write on the server instead of writing in client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer and I can't believe it was that simple. In my Startup.cs file I had set cookie policy:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

Because during the development mode I was consistently using the application and in the initial stages I had given permission for setting cookie but soon after that I removed code need to set the permission true by user as it was the development stage.

I just changed above into this:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

And now cookies are being set without any issue.